# Do all Compact Spaces of Constant Positive Sectional Curvature Have Periodic Geodesic Flow

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

My research is mainly in Harmonic analysis, so I'm not sure if I'm missing some subtleties with the following Differential Geometry argument:

The unit sphere has periodic geodesic flow, of period $2 \pi$. By the Killing Hopf Theorem, every manifold with constant positive sectional curvature must be a quotient of the sphere by a group acting freely and properly discontinuously. Does it follow from this that all manifolds with constant positive sectional curvature equal to one must have a periodic geodesic flow, with period at most $2 \pi$?

Comment: Note that the radius of the sphere depends in the curvature.

Comment: Thanks - I've edited the statement to say that the compact manifold has constant sectional curvature 1 now. Is this still an issue when we restrict to such manifolds?

Comment: Try to prove this. See if you get stuck anywhere. You need to know basics of the covering theory such as the path-lifting property.

Comment: I research problems on manifolds from the perspectiveof harmonic analysis, so I don't have the time to devote to all the technical details that arise from a more topological perspective. I have an intuitive proof (any geodesic on a discrete quotient of the sphere by a group action of isometries lifts to a geodesic on the sphere, which must be periodic), but need someone more comfortable with these technical details to point out if there is some subtle problem with this argument - is there such a problem?